# How to change the order of Sharepoint Online User Profile Custom Properties efficiently with Powershell?

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, user-profile-property

So, I have managed to create a custom property for user profiles in Sharepoint Online. However, the new property shows up all the way at the bottom of the the list of properties, and the only way in the GUI to move it up is to click the up button next to the user profile property and move it up one line at a time, which is exceedingly tedious.

[image]

I have looked online for more efficient ways to change the order of properties, but all the Powershell scripts I have found only apply to Sharepoint 2013 (or other on-premise server versions too, I assume) - for example: https://www.evokeit.com/blog/reordering-user-profile-properties-on-microsoft-sharepoint

Is there any way to change the script to work for Sharepoint Online, or is there some other easy way to move properties around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PowerShell code that you referred only works for SharePoint On-premise.

From [the article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/work-with-user-profiles-in-sharepoint), Creating or changing user profiles and user profile properties and attributes only could be implemented by SSOM, and can't be done by CSOM/JSOM/REST. So, I am afraid you have to change the order via GUI instead of PowerShell/code.